# Uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

While i was doing some problems, i have encountered this question and i am really stuck. question is the following

Suppose that $X_1, \cdots \cdots, X_n$ IID and $X \sim unif\{1, \cdots \cdots , \theta\} , \ \theta \in \mathbb{N}$

Let $T = X_{(n)} = max \{X_1, \cdots \cdots, X_n \}$

I have already shown that T is a sufficient and complete statistics. Now I was trying to show that T is also a UMVUE by computing $\mathbb{E}_\theta (T)$.

here is my attempt and where i got stuck.

$\mathbb{E}_\theta (T) = \sum_{t=1}^\theta t \cdot \frac{1}{\theta^n} \cdot [t^n - (t-1)^n] = \frac{1}{\theta^n}\sum_{t=1}^\theta [t^{n+1} - t \cdot (t-1)^n] = \theta - \sum_{t=1}^{\theta-1}\Big(\frac{t}{\theta} \Big)^n $

and I can't simplify this last part of the sum to get a closed form solution. is there a neater way to solve this instead of hard bashing?

Comment: You don't need to compute the expectation: you only need to establish whether or not the expectation equals $\theta.$  Your final expression makes the answer to that question abundantly clear.

Comment: @whuber would it be sufficient to say that $$as \ n \rightarrow \infty , \mathbb{E}_\theta (T) \rightarrow \theta \ wP_\theta \ ?$$

Comment: Are you asking about unbiased estimation or about *asymptotically* unbiased estimation?

Comment: @whuber about unbiased estimation. I think i made a little mistake. T is not UMVUE, but $\frac{n}{n+1} T$ should be the unbiased estimator?

Comment: Clearly it's not, since certainly $T \le \theta.$  That implies $Tn/(n+1)$ strictly less than $\theta,$ too, which means it cannot be unbiased.